# ESLint - 'process' is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using ESLinter for a simple node project. Below is the only code I have in index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        hi: 'there'
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

I am using `VSCode` editor. It automatically runs ESLint for JS code.

In the IDE, I see below error for last but one line -

```
[eslint] 'process' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

Any Idea what's wrong?

Comment: does ESLINT have some way of informing it you are linting nodejs code?

Comment: You probably haven't configured eslint correctly. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling - It was so dumb of me not looking into .eslintrc.json file. I had accidentally selected `browser default global variables`. Your link hinted me to that. Now, the error is gone!

Answer (score 346, accepted):

When I got error I had `"browser": true` instead of `"node": true`.

I have fixed this with following config for `.eslintrc.json` file-

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2015
    }
}
```

Thanks @FelixKling and @Jaromanda X for quick responses.

Comment: This got rid of my ESlint 'URL' is not defined, too.

Comment: In my case I was missing the ```node: true``` on my env eslint config file.

Comment: Adding the `"node" : true` worked for me also with this issue.

Comment: Thought I selected "node" in the wizard at npm init @eslint/config but seems I didn't heh

Answer (score 108):

Adding "node": "true" to an existing list of environments will do the job, too

```
"env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
       }
```

Answer (score 62):

Add .eslintrc file to root of your project (if you don't already have one) and define globals to ignore

```
{
    "globals": {
        "process": true
      }
}
```

Make sure you use process.env though out the project but only in a single configuration file. Consider adding `no-process-env`rule.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-process-env

Comment: This is useful if you're using a bundler like [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), which exposes `process` in a browser context.

Comment: This is the correct way if your're implementing a frontend application.

Answer (score 35):

If you have eslint installed, add `env: { node: true }` to the .eslintrc.js file

Answer (score 11):

**This config helped me and can help others too.**

```json
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "useJSXTextNode": true,
    "warnOnUnsupportedTypeScriptVersion": false
  },
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "extends": [ "eslint:recommended"],
  }
}
```

Comment: I just had to add "parser": "babel-eslint" to my .eslintrc.json file

Answer (score 7):

**When working on the node js project. This might help you. It is working on my end.**

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the error even after settng  `"node": true,` remember to install `@types/node` with

```sh
npm i -D @types/node

yarn add -D @types/node
```

Answer (score 1):

### Add these env lines in your `.eslintrc.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "node": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [new ESLint configuration file](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#goodbye-environments%2C-hello-globals) eslint.config.js, the `env` property has been removed so you should use the `languageOptions.globals` property:

```js
import globals from 'globals';

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, when most other scripts are meant to run in a browser environment, [you can add a special comment](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#using-configuration-comments) to the top of a file:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
```

Note that it has to be a block comment style; an inline style comment (`//`) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to enable Node Core library
Within WebStorm:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM
2. Make sure that 'Node.js Core library is enabled' by pressing Enable
   button.
3. Click OK for saving settings.

Answer (score -6):

Another remedy for this issue is to simply `import process from "process"`.

Even though it's not strictly necessary, one could argue it's better practice anyway.