# eslint complains about __dirname not being defined in a NodeJS file

Tags: eslint

I've just started using eslint.  I initialized it and started fixing problems it pointed out.
One problem, however, it shouldn't complain about:

```js
const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, _FILENAME));
```

The error is:

```
error  '__dirname' is not defined
```

I did some searching and found that when you add `--experimental` to the node command that `__dirname` is not defined.  This, however, isn't the case for me.  I'm not running node with the `--experimental` flag.

See these questions:

- [Alternative for __dirname in Node.js when using ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-js-when-using-es6-modules)
- [__dirname is not defined in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983656/dirname-is-not-defined-in-nodejs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Use `process.cwd()` instead

Comment: Also you may check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62892482/13163131

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is \_\_dirname not defined in node REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817423/why-is-dirname-not-defined-in-node-repl)

Comment: Won't `process.cwd()` give the current working directory of the process? Sometimes you want the path of the (possibly included or required) file instead.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is happening because ESLint does not know that your code is supposed to be used in Node.js: `__dirname` is not defined in browsers and also not defined in ES modules. To tell ESLint that your code will run in Node.js as a CommonJS module, open your ESLint config and set `node: true` in the `env` section. If you are using .eslintrc.json:

```js
{
    "env": {
        "node": true
    }
}
```

There are also other ways to specify environments, they are explained in the [related documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments).

Comment: That is (to me) strange because when I ran `npm init @eslint/config`, I selected **NodeJS** as the runtime environment.  I'm not sure why **browser** was selected.  When I deleted `browser: true` and put in `node: true`, the problem went away.  Thank you.

Comment: Apparently when using `npm init @eslint/config` we need to choose between browser or node by pressing the letter `i` to change the option instead of navigating with arrows.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same. Adding this to .eslintrc.json fixed it for me:

```
"globals": {
    "__dirname": true
}
```

Got the idea from this similar question about the `process` global: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777068/936907

Comment: I think this one is more reasonable since some projects have default global variables and this is the way to tell the Eslint which should be allowed. Thanks